# error while importing R in the tutorial

Tags: android

Hello i am using tutorial downloaded from [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html) . The problem is R.java is given `com.example.android.merge`  package instead of gen folder and there is error on R. I have tried to put in gen folder but still there is error  .How can i remove it . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the R.java that you have and then clean and rebuild it again... so that you will be able to generate the R.java again in the gen folder... Hope this could solve your problem...

Comment: As i am using eclipse , so when i delete R it automatically generates R but in this case its not creating

Comment: while others are on imports import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

Comment: i have checked in the java build path  there it is saying unable to select system library

Comment: one more thing i have found that there is no R.layout.okcancelbar in the layout folder

Comment: i think you have import/open this project as an java project... which may be cause of that... better remove it and open it as an android existing project... hope you could understand wat i m saying...

Answer (score 0):

Remove both the non-generated and generated R classes.  Make sure you select a project build target in the android window of project properties.  Fix project properties by right-clicking the project and selecting "Fix Project Properties" in "Android Tools".  Finally, Clean the project by selecting "Clean..." from the "Project" menu.